# Is there a way I can make a hollow object solid?

Tags: modeling, mirror

Yesterday i managed to create this shape that is similar to a teardrop.

Front view:
[image]

Side view:
[image]

I then mirrored it on the Z axis using the mirror modifier like this:[image]

But the shape is hollow from the inside and that creates a problem when I render it as glass, because instead of passing through a solid object, the light simply passes through 2 glass planes.

Is there a way to create a solid object from a hollow one ? I haven't been able to find a sort of "Fill" function that does that.

Comment: I think there are some misconceptions about 3D modeling and "filled" objects here. 

3D modeling tools always create "hollow" hulls. There is no such thing as a "solid" object. If an object appears to be solid it's just an illusion created by using the right material shaders. 

As always, it would of course be important to know what the purpose of your model is (still render, animation, game engine asset) to give an appropriate answer.

Comment: Could be that the normals are not in the right direction. I'd suggest applying the mirror modifier, check that all the vertices of the two halves are correctly joined so that the inside is properly enclosed and then check that the normals are all pointing outwards (should be able to do that by selecting "recalculate normals".

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the soldify modifier. This lets you change the thickness and tweak it later on.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong. This object is solid (filled). There are no "2 glass planes" This is one solid object. For make walls you can use **"Solidify"** modifier. Or in edit mode copy all, scale it, select only inner part and invert normals. Normals determine which side of face is inner, and which is outer. Face "as is" have zero thickness.