# How to make hollow object with only surface into solid?

Tags: python, modeling

I kept creating a hollow cylinder by spinning a curve [[Example]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114126/how-do-i-draw-a-parametric-column-or-cylinder-with-varying-radius-using-python). 
This is the hollow cylinder I made by spinning a second-order polynomial curve. The cylinder would be hollow but not "filled" or not "solid".

[image]

After I exported it into STL, it is still hollow. However, I need the cylinder to be solid. So is there a function to spin a surface to make a solid object using python script? If not, is there any other way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific and add a screenshot and or the blend file.

Comment: @TechTornado Thank you. Do you think it is now more clear? Basically, I tried to make a "solid" cylinder with varying radius with respect to its height.

Comment: Yes that was all I needed to see. Also there are many times where you may need to use python scripts but always remember that they make things more complicated and don't always work the way you want, so try to do whatever you can without them.

Comment: @TechTornado Gotcha. My goal is not to create a single cylinder. I need to create a huge amount of parametric columns between points in space. Only Python can make it much more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried using [*Array* modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html)?

Comment: @TechTornado I have not... Each column has a different profile, and some profiles are very random (e.g. Biological foam materials). So it's not simply duplicating.

Comment: Making first and last points of curve on axis will close top and bottom with a fan.

Comment: @HSChan What exactly are you trying to make? It almost sounds like an object particle system.

Comment: @TechTornado Open cell foam. http://www.foardpanel.com/open-vs-closed-cell-foams/ there are lots of branches connecting to each other.

Comment: @batFINGER Do you mean adding one more vertice on the spin axis to kind of enclosing the curve then spin it?

Comment: Yes.  Could use `(0, 0, max(z))` at top, and `(0, 0, min(z))` at bottom to make flat ends. Or use circle formula top and bottom to make rounded end. As long as first and last pt sit on axis.

Comment: btw are you using mesh or curve version? above will work for either. Might need to build curve top to bottom or  to screw it the other way to get normals pointing out. (Note also this is covered in answer below re finish outline before spinning)

Comment: @batFINGER I am using the mesh version. Is getting normals pointing out a step to make the spun object "solid"?

Comment: In general  have normals pointing out. (noticed it too late after posting bmesh answer)

Comment: @batFINGER Enclosed the curve and spun it. It still gives me a hollow cylinder. The normals are pointing out. Is it even possible to revolve a surface to create a "solid" object in Blender? Or perhaps there is another way?

Comment: Re terminology of "solid" : Do you consider the default UV sphere to be a "solid" object?  It is after all a semi circle spun around z axis.

Comment: @batFINGER Yes. I exported an STL for a sphere and opened it with Netfabb. I cut it along the cross-section and it showed me a solid object. It doesn't work for my cylinder.

Comment: Try removing  doubles, (or hit merge on screw modifier (& possibly apply))  before exporting.

Comment: @batFINGER Oh... Great. I think I know what you are saying about the "solid" object and removing doubles and merging vertices. I tried a model repair function in Netfabb and the hollow cylinder becomes "solid". I believe there must be some duplicated vertices or other unwanted geometry.

Comment: The verts on axis when spun (without merge) are really an N (spins) point circle merged to a point.  A closed hole. Nethingy must need a manifold to be consider an object solid. As well as the seam  at 0 and 360.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you didn't finish the outline before you spun the model, so now you have three options. [See the blender documentation for the *Spin* function.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html)

1. You can modify your outline to have a top and bottom and re-spin it.
2. Select *Edge Ring* and press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face.

   2.1 Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to *Poke* the face, thus making a triangle fan.
3. You can use *Grid Fill* or from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> menu.

[image]

Comment: I tried modifying the outline by adding top and bottom and spin it. I exported the model as STL file and opened it with Netfabb. It still is a hollow cylinder when I looked at the cross-section. I think my question is similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62330/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-a-hollow-object-solid?rq=1. But there is no useful answer.

Comment: @HSChan Some programs don't like triangles (tris) and ngons. Try using the grid fill method.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the outline and repaired the model in Netfabb. It actually turned the hollow cylinder into a "solid" object. It could be the duplicated vertices in the original model. I didn't remove doubles or merge vertices before.

Comment: @HSChan I'm happy it worked. Good luck.